# Is Loki younger or the same age as Thor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-ragnarok

In many places Loki is described as Thor's youngest brother. However, in Thor:Ragnarok, Thor is talking about an incident from their childhood

> This one time when we were children he transformed himself into a snake and he knows I love snakes so I went to pick up the snake to admire it and he transformed back into himself and was like “YARGH IT’S ME!” and then he stabbed me. **We were eight at the time.**

So if they were both eight, then they should be the same age.

Comment: One is younger than another if they are born minutes later. They could also have been born 11 months apart and still both be 8.

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82458/how-old-are-thor-loki-odin-and-asgardians-in-earth-years-in-marvel-movies Age already answered here, And as Edlothiad said, he can be yunger than Thor by mare minutes or 11 moths and still be same age.

Comment: I like the sheer amount of ignorance shown in that Wikipedia page. Basically it says: Thor has lived for thousands years, he is about a thousand years old and he practiced his skill for many millenia (which again means many thousand years)

Comment: Yeah Wiki is know for doing that. Anyway another thought crossed my mind. We use Earth years to count how old Thor and Loki are. Is Ashard year and Earth years same length?  I mean if Asgard year is longer than ours there can be 10 Earth years apart and still be in same age by Asgard standards. I have to look into that and maybe post a question

Comment: Remember, Loki is adopted...

Comment: @Vanja Moreover, he doesn't really say eight whats. Could be they were both eight blinplorgs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's explicitly stated in [Thor](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Thor_(film)) that Thor is the **elder** son.

> **ODIN:** *Gungnir. Its aim is true, its power strong. With it I have
>   defended Asgard and the lives of the innocent across the Nine Realms
>   since the time of the Great Beginning. And though the day has come for
>   a new King to wield his own weapon -- that duty remains the same. Thor
>   Odinson, my heir, my **first-born.***

Given that Loki is adopted, it's very possible that he's *actually* the elder of the pair, but he's never acknowledged as such, even after the truth comes out.

Comment: But first-born is a reference to the first child that was actually his.  I have a son but if I now adopt an older child, my son will still be my first-born son, even if he is now younger than his brother.

Comment: @KennyPeanuts - Except that at this point it was a secret that Loki was adopted.

Answer (score 3):

According to the captions from Thor 1, the Jotun vs. Asgardian battle took place in 965 AD. That's when we see infant Jotun!Loki.  In Avengers: Infinity War, Thor said he was 1500 years old (ref: https://movieweb.com/thor-age-avengers-infinity-war/). If Loki isn't even 1100, then Thor is definitely physically older.
I think I read somewhere that the "snake story" scene in Thor: Ragnarok was improvised, but I couldn't quickly find a confirming source--either way, that movie relied pretty heavily on "Americanized" humor and though it's a stretch, you could almost justify that Thor was just throwing out a random young age off the top of his head to give Bruce an idea as to about how old they were in human years.

Answer (score 2):

[From my answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/229519/31394)

In Thor, when speaking to Odin, he clarifies that they are not gods, nor immortal, to which Loki responds "Give or take 5,000 years".

If we do some math and say 5,000 is the average life expectancy of a typical Asgardian, and divide that by 80 years here on earth, we get 62.5.

According to Norse Mythology, Thor should have been a few hundred years old in 965 A.D. during the battle with the Frost Giants to conquer earth. Loki was found/taken after the war, as seen in the first Thor movie.

Around 1,000 years before Tony Stark declared "I am Iron Man" in 2008, Odin took the Casket and Loki, making Loki's birth year around 965 A.D.

2008 - 965 = 1043 Asgardian years old

1043/62.5 = 16.688 Earth years old

Thor stated in Infinity War that he was “around 1500 years old” https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/04/30/avengers-infinity-war-thors-real-age-revealed/. As I.W. was set in 2018, this would set Thor’s birth at around 520 A.D. (518 A.D. specifically).

2018 - 518 = 1500 Asgardian years old

1500/62.5 = 24 Earth years old

His birth year being 518 A.D. would put him at 447 years old when Loki was born.

447/62.5 = 7.152 Earth years old

Comment: "*Around **1,000 years** before Tony Stark declared "I am Iron Man" in 2008, Odin took the Casket and Loki, making Loki's birth year around 965 A.D."* - Can you back this up with a reference since it directly conflicts with Thor's statement of their respective ages.

Comment: Back up his date of birth?

Comment: Yes. The quote from Thor (above) suggests that they're much the same age. Your assertion is that Thor is half a millennium older. That needs to be backed up

Comment: Well, when we see Loki in 965 A.D. he is a baby, who looks to have been born quiet recently. So I do believe that is his date of birth. We don't a specific date of birth for Thor, but he stated he was 1500 years old in Infinity War. Simple math (2018 - 1500) sets his birth in 518 A.D.

Comment: OK. Now find a reference that proves it (a bit of dialogue, for instance) and add it into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a plot point in *Thor: Ragnarok* that Hela is the true first born of Odin and therefore has a claim to the throne of Asgard.   Thus we can conclude that the throne of Asgard is determined by primogeniture (goes to the first born).   Therefore, since Loki didn't make a claim on that basis (adopted or not) we can take this as evidence that Thor is older.

(Counterpoints could be that he is not natural born, or that he was adopted after Thor's birth and was therefore not actually "the first child", however since there was never any dialog justifying Thor's claim along these line, I think it's safe to say it's probably just that Thor is older.)